# Program not functionning correctly

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function person(name, age){
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;
     }

        var ulysse = new person("Ulysse Corbeil", 18);
        var taylor = new person("Taylor Swift", 21);


     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(taylor.age);
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I am new to javascript and maybe this will seem like a rooky error, but when I inspect the code, it says that I didn't declare taylor correctly, any idea why?

Comment: You don't need the "type" attribute at all.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling error on `<script type="text/javascipt">`. It should be javascript. Missed the R